# A tuprolog syntax error.Syntax error at/before line -1

Tags: prolog, tuprolog

I am new to prolog. I have a .pl file consulting normally on swi-prolog, but when I consult it on tu-prolog, crazy things always happen. Here are parts of my codes.

```
    :- dynamic(assignopT/6).
    :- multifile(assignopT/6).
    assignopT(30246,30244,30210,30247,+,30248).
```

When I consulted it on tu-prolog,it said syntax error at/before line 12219,which is the third line above. It work all right on swi-prolog. Then I thought maybe there is something wrong with +, so I changed it to this.

```
    assignopT(30246,30244,30210,30247,'+',30248).
```

This time,it said syntax error at/before line -1. I really don't get this, what line -1 even suppose to mean. The .pl named swi2tu.pl is on https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B4KCEwRVmr_yWjQwOEp3LWpYdk0&usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try instead:

```
assignopT(30246,30244,30210,30247,(+),30248).
```

Writing an atom, such as `+`, between single quotes changes nothing and the error is possibly due to its operator status. Assuming that's the case, writing it between ()'s should fix the possible operator conflict when loading the code in tuProlog (not Turbo Prolog, I assume!).

Comment: Yeah,it's tuProlog. I had done what you said, but it didn't work out. Writing + between () didn't fix the problem, the same error is still at the same line.

Comment: If the tuProlog parser is not compliant with official and de facto Prolog standards, you may need to find an alternative representation for 5th argument. Btw, does the version of tuProlog you're using supports multifile predicates?

Comment: Yes,it supports multifile predicates.I found the reason and fixed it yesterday. There was a utf-8 character in the .pl file. The value of the utf-8 character is U+FFFF ,and the tuProlog stops parsing when it meets U+FFFF, which is the reason of syntax error at/before line -1. But the swi-prolog can parser U+FFFF, which I still not understand.

Comment: `U+FFFF` is not a valid Unicode code point. It seems that SWI-Prolog is ignoring it. I suggest you confirm by asking on the SWI-Prolog mailing list. Glad you found the error.

Comment: It's great to have your help. I will ask them soon

Comment: The official answer from swi-prolog is below. It simply doesn't care whether the character code is valid Unicode or not.  To SWI-Prolog, character sequences are basically strings of integers 0..0x10ffff (0..0xffff on Windows).  It may run into trouble doing certain actions on them, in which case it might raise exceptions.